# Wordpress wp_create_user error 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem with the wp_creae_user() function.
I have to create a large number of users with a loop.

There is an example code

```
$count = 0; 
$name = 'userTry';
while($count < 10) {
    $user_email = 'gggghhhtttffrr'.$count.'@mmmvvff.com';
    $user_name = $name.$count;

    $user_id = username_exists( $user_name ); // Check if username already exist

    if ( ! $user_id && false == email_exists( $user_email ) ) {
        $random_password = wp_generate_password( $length = 12, $include_standard_special_chars = false );
        $user_id = wp_create_user( $user_name, $random_password, $user_email );
    }
    $count++;
}
```

When I execute the script I got a 502 Bad Gateway

On the error log, I have this error

```
upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream
```

how I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you insert user same site or out of site? more clarification

Comment: Yes user are in same site. I just created a page template with that code. When i open the page the script start.

Comment: tested in localhost working good

Comment: https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/890

Comment: i can't understand how fix it...
If the loop have only 5 user, all work fine..
If have more the 5 user got the 502 error

Comment: try this one github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/890